# Potential leak of an object stored into setting username and setting password value

Tags: iphone

I am analyzing my application and face Potential leak of an object stored into setting username and setting password value my code is given

```
-(void) checkRememberPassword{
        CFStringRef userNameKey = CFSTR("user_id_preferences");
        CFStringRef settingUserName = (CFStringRef)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(userNameKey, kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication);
        CFStringRef passwordKey = CFSTR("password_preferences");
        CFStringRef settingPasswordValue = (CFStringRef)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(passwordKey, kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication);
        NSString *tempString = (__bridge NSString *)settingPasswordValue;
        NSString *tempString1 = (__bridge NSString *)settingUserName;
        if(([tempString1 length] != 0) || ([tempString length] !=0)){
            txtUserName.text = (__bridge NSString *)settingUserName;
            txtPassword.text = (__bridge NSString *)settingPasswordValue;
            [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_full.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            flagForRemPassword = YES;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string returned by CFPreferencesCopyAppValue follows the Create rule (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) in Core Foundation -- you need to call CFRelease when you are finished with it. ARC does *not* do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CFBridgingRelease` to transfer ownership of the object to ARC, instead of a simple C-style cast:

```
NSString *tempString = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(settingPasswordValue);
```